# How to set FA icon as a button, React

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

*Using React, free FA icons*

I want FA icon as a button, how can I do that?
My effort: `<button onClick={handleLogout}><FontAwesomeIcon className="logouticon" icon={faArrowRightFromBracket} color="white" /></button>`
But it is not working, because the icon is behind the blank default button design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to use button for on click event. Then you can remove it and add on click to fa icon

```
<FontAwesomeIcon className="logouticon" icon={faArrowRightFromBracket} color="white" onClick={handleLogout} />
```